# java xml, create self closing tag

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I'm using the Xerces xml library in java.

I'm able to create an element like:

`Element myElement = doc.createElement("element");`

which would result in `<element></element>`.

How would I create an element that would result in a self closing tag like so?

`<element/>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For example you if you need to create an XML like

```
 xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootElement>
   <element />
</RootElement>
```

we can have our snippet of java code like the below.

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class XmlTransformer{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xml = "";
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("RootElement");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Element myElement = doc.createElement("element");
            rootElement.appendChild(myElement);
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

            transformer.transform(source, result);
            xml = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(" xml \n \n " +xml);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```